# Copying only the letters in a vector to another vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I need to find only the letters in a 2-dimensional vector and copy them to a one dimensional vector. For example, the vector could contain:

```
3    4    5
A    B 
A    C
A    B
B    C
1    C    3
```

Then, the new vector would contain:

```
A    B   C
```

The letters shouldn't be repeated. 
This is part of a bigger project and I'm stuck in this part.

Comment: This sounds like homework.  So I'll only tell you (1) there is a function to tell if a `char` is a letter ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha ); and (2) it may make sense to copy the letters to something else before copying them to the final `std::vector<char>`, like, say, a `std::set<char>` ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/ ) (alternatively, you can copy all the letters to the final `std::vector<char>` and then get rid of the duplicates ( `std::sort()`, `std::unique()` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/ , and calling `erase()` on the vector)).

Comment: @Jack Edit your code into the question so people can answer what the problem with it is.

Comment: @Galik Done. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a `vector` of `vector`s?  How are we supposed to know where you are going wrong if you don't show us your code?  You say `vector` but use `string` in your code.  As for deleting the repeated values, `sort` them and then use the algorithm `unique`.

Comment: @graham.reeds Thanks, I got it to work.

Comment: @MaxLybbert Thank you! Your answer got me in the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had these two vectors:

```
vector<vector<string>> gateInputs; //2D vector with data
vector<string> Letters; // Vector where I'll store only the letters
```

I was told to use `isalpha`, but it only works with `char` and my vector is of type `string`, so I used the following function:

```
bool all_alpha(const std::string& str)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    if (!std::isalpha(str[i])) return false;
}
```

Then I called that function to store only the letters in my vector `Letters`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <gateInputs.size(); i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j<gateInputs[i].size(); j++)
    {
        if (all_alpha(gateInputs[i][j]))
        {
            string m = gateInputs[i][j];
            Letters.push_back(m);
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked. Now the vector `Letters` contains the following:

```
A   B  A  C  A  B  B  C  C
```

Then I just had to sort the vector and delete the duplicates:

```
// Sort letters in vector
sort(Letters.begin(), Letters.end());
// Erase duplicates
Letters.erase(unique(Letters.begin(), Letters.end()), Letters.end());
```

And done! The array now contains:

```
A    B    C
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of which letters you've seen using an array:

```
bool seen[26] = { false };
for (const auto& v : v2d)
    for (const auto& c : v)
        if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
            seen[c - 'A'] = true;
std::string result;
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
    if (seen[c - 'A']) result += c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong container for Letters. Change your vector on set and you will get right behavior:

```
std::set<string> Letters;
```